Calling Super function from child function
I have the following structure:
class grandparent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_obj(self):
        pass

class ParentBase(grandparent):
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        self.obj1 = obj1

    def get_obj(self,func):
        return getattr(self.obj1, func)

    def get_base_obj(self):
        return super().get_obj('base') 
  
        
class child1(ParentBase):
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        super().__init__(obj1)

    def get_obj(self):
         return super().get_base_obj().getChild1()
        

class child2(ParentBase):
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        super().__init__(obj1)

    def get_obj(self):
        return super().get_base_obj().getChild2()
        

Running this code:

child_instance = child1(obj1)
child_instance.get_obj()

Will give me the error 2 arguments inputted but 1 expected because get_base_obj in parent calls the grandparent definition.
If I change the function to:
def get_base_obj(self, func_name):
    return self.get_obj(func)

it will call the child class definition and also error out.
I want get_base_obj in the parent class to call get_obj in the parent class when get_obj is called from a child class. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to make parent.get_obj a class function? parentBase is a base class so there will be no initalisation from there

Edit:
changing the parentBase class to this seems to work but its not very nice:
class ParentBase(grandparent):
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        self.obj1 = obj1

    def get_obj(self,func):
        return self.obj1

    def get_base_obj(self):
        return ParentBase.get_obj(self, 'base') 


child1 is a class, not a method. It's not clear what you expect .child1() to do.

None of your classes have a base attribute, what is super().get_obj('base') supposed to return?

What is obj1? Without that I cannot run your code.

child1 is a function that is in the base object that is in obj1
Essentially the hierarchy is
Obj1 --> base --> child1, child2
I want to run the child1 function on the base from child1 class, and run the child2 function on the base from the child2 class

Your issue here is misunderstanding inheritance.
You have a Parent class and a Child class that inherits it.
When you do c = Child(42) you have ONE object, not a parent object and a child object- c. Everywhere in the class heirarchy where you see self its referring to the same object. It doesn't make sense to try and get some object that lives on the "parent" self object- because there isn't one. Super() isn't returning an instance of the parent class- it's a proxy to call the method of the parent class and pass in the current self as the first argument.
Now- you CAN store data on the Class object. Consider this-
class Registry:
  stored_object = None

  @classmethod
  def store(cls, some_obj):
    cls.stored_object = some_obj

  def setup(self, some_obj):
    self.store(some_obj)

a = Registry()
a.store(42)
print(a.stored_object)  # 42
b = Registry()
print(b.stored_object)  # 42

As you can see, both child objects (instances of the Registry class) can access the global singleton Registry object (which is an instance of the type class). Another thing to think about, is you can keep a reference in an object to another object and have methods refer to that. Consider
class Base:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value


class Child(Base):
  def __init__(self, value, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    super().__init__(value)

  def show(self):
    print(self.parent.value)

class Parent(Base):
  def spawn_child(self, child_value):
    return Child(child_value, self)

p = Parent(42)
c = p.spawn_child(22)
c.show()

Now- I only have a vague idea of what you were actually trying to accomplish, so not sure if this helps at all- but hopefully explains the behaviors you observed.
